# Angular2- referencing child components into a parent template as "string" to create them dynamically

Tags: angular

Creating a header component dynamically by constructing the required template as string and sending it to the dynamic component builder.

Dynamic components created taking reference from [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3DsBxdOhd670TlIjl8Js?p=preview) plunker, using the same component `HtmlOutlet directive`,

the string passed to this component is constructed as :

```
    prepareHeaderHtml(): string {
            this.property = this.headerObj;
            let headerTemplate = '<div class="header">';
            for (let headerValues in this.property) {
                let headerValue = this.property[0]["value"];
                headerTemplate += `<ul>
                                        <span class="fa fa-home"></span>&nbsp;
                                        ${headerValue}
                                        <span class="title" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">
                                          <img class="notify-circle" src="img/notify_3.png">&nbsp; ${user} &nbsp;
                                          <img class="user-circle" src="img/profile.png">
                                        </span>
                                  </ul>`;
            }
            headerTemplate += '</div>';
            return headerTemplate
        }
```

The requirement is to create a Alert component and Notification component, which will be a child component of the Header component.

Both the components can be created separately in the same manner as the Header component.

**Question:**

How can the Alert and Notification components be referenced into the Header Component so that along with the Header the Alert and Notification components gets dynamically created.